# Azure WebJobs: Is it possible to retrieve the Host Url programmatically in the console app?

Tags: c#, azure, console-application, azure-webjobs, azure-sdk-.net

I would like to invoke a REST call from my WebJob, I am wondering if it is possible to programmatically retrieve the Host Url (`http://<something>.azurewebsites.net`) from inside my WebJob, instead of hard-coding the URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Web App hostname can be read from the `WEBSITE_HOSTNAME` environment variable.

A description of the environment, including environment variables can be found [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment). Environment variables and their values can be viewed using the Kudu dashboard at `https://<web_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net`.

Answer (score 0):

In your queue monitoring method you can pass a reference to CloudStorageAccount and get the queue endpoint, e.g:

```
    public async Task ProcessQueueMessageAsync([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, CloudStorageAccount account)
    {
        var endpoint = account.QueueEndpoint;
    }
```